# Compile Error: User-defined type not defined Access/Excel Reference

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I receive the message `Compile Error: User-defined type not defined` in a function when declaring an Excel object. I have my reference set to Microsoft Office Object Library 14.0.

```
Function GetAIRR(arrAssCF, arrAssDate, Guess) As Double
    Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
    Set objExcel = New Excel.Application

    Target = objExcel.Application.Xirr(arrAssCF, arrAssDate, Guess)
End Function
```

Comment: Is this an MS Access Macro?

Comment: Do you have `Option Explicit` specified? What is `Target`? Is `Guess` defined anywhere? The function isn't returning anything, its return value is never assigned. What line gets highlighted when you get the compile error?

Comment: Do you have a reference to the Microsoft Excel Object Library? Just the Office one isn't enough if you're working from Access.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth oh wow, I totally glossed that over! Indeed, Office object model won't give you an `Excel.Application` class! That doesn't fix everything else that's wrong with this code though.

Answer (score 3):

Reference the **Microsoft Excel** type library (i.e. not the *Microsoft Office* type library).

You can browse the types and their members exposed by a type library using the VBE's *Object Browser* (F2). If there's no `Excel` library and no `Application` class other than the one define in the `Access` library, you're missing a reference.

Then...

Make the function explicitly `Public`, the array parameters explicitly `ByRef`, the non-array parameters explicitly `ByVal`, give them all an explicit declared type.

```
Public Function GetAIRR(ByRef arrAssCF As Variant, ByRef arrAssDate As Variant, ByVal Guess As Long) As Double
```

`Guess` could probably of type `xlGuess`, but that's ...well, a *guess*. `Long` should be good enough, but if an enum exists that could make it easier for the calling code to know what to pass for that parameter, use it.

You don't need a local `Excel.Application` variable - just have a `With` block hold that reference for you:

```
With New Excel.Application
    Target = .Xirr(arrAssCF, arrAssDate, Guess)
End With
```

Lastly, the `Target` variable doesn't seem to be declared anywhere, and the function isn't returning anything. Did you mean to do this?

```
With New Excel.Application
    GetAIRR = .Xirr(arrAssCF, arrAssDate, Guess)
End With
```

Note that invoking the `Xirr` function off `Excel.Application` is a late-bound call that will be resolved at run-time, and if something goes wrong with it, you'll get a *type mismatch* error when `GetAIRR` (a `Double`) is tentatively assigned to some `Error` value.

By using `Excel.WorksheetFunction.Xirr` instead, the call is early-bound (i.e. resolved at compile-time), and if something goes wrong with it, the function will *raise* an actual run-time error instead of *returning* one; you can handle that error with normal error handling, or you can suppress either error and return `0`, if that's an acceptable thing for this function to do:

```
    With New Excel.Application
        On Error Resume Next
        'possible type mismatch if input is invalid
        GetAIRR = .Xirr(arrAssCF, arrAssDate, Guess)

        'or early-bound:
        'possible error 1004 if input is invalid
        'GetAIRR = .WorksheetFunction.Xirr(arrAssCF, arrAssDate, Guess) 

        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
```

Comment: Personally, I'd also remove the `.Application`. While using `Application.Application.Something` is valid (or `Application.Application.Application.Something`, or even more), it feels a little ridiculous to me.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth gah'! absolutely! this is what I get for coding in a browser tab...

Answer (score 0):

`.Xirr` is a WorksheetFunction. Use the following:

`Application.WorksheetFunction.Xirr(arrAssCF, arrAssDate, Guess)`

Comment: There is **a lot** more wrong going on, and `Application.Sum` is just a late-bound call to `Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum` - In other words this answer doesn't address the problem at all.

Comment: Cheap shot, on second thought... let the downvotes begin.